# Making a custom listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

If I want to make a custom listbox by inheriting from the ListBox class and overriding some functions, should I be making a User Control or a Custom Control? I've read that I should be using a user control but when I add a user control, it comes with a panel control in the designer that I can't remove whereas custom control is blank and I can drag anything to it.

And when I try to change `public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl` to `public partial class UserControl1 : ListBox` for a User Control, VS doesn't add properties like `AutoScaleMode` and `AutoScaleDimensions`.

Comment: Autoscaling is the job of the container, not the list box.  Deriving from ListBox is correct, don't call it UserControl1.

Comment: I just used the default settings in VS as an example.  Deriving from ListBox as User Control form produces an error cause VS doesn't auto-adjust the settings.  Which is why I'm asking if User Control is appropriate or Custom Control should be used instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UserControl is a container control. It doesn't "come with" a Panel - it *is* a sort of "panel" (but not a Panel - that's just an empty ContainerControl). So you can position them. A custom control is just derived from Control and you create and position things purely in code, though usually you wouldn't have subcontrols in a simple Control.

As for inheriting from ListBox, you have to add those properties yourself, unless I'm misunderstanding completely.

By the way, if you just need to draw custom elements in the ListBox, but not change functionality, consider owner-drawing the ListBox instead. There are many examples on the Internet.

Comment: I'm asking whether User Control or Custom Control is used for making a custom control from an existing winforms control.  When I inherit from ListBox in Custom Control, visual studio and intellisense automatically adjusts while doing the same for User Control doesn't work.

Comment: @Jack: Neither. You inherit, if possible. (If it's not, you might use a custom control. Not usually a user control, though.)

Comment: What do you mean by inherit? If one wants to modify an existing control, they'll need to make a user control/custom control and inherit from it anyways.

Comment: @Jonas: Inherit from `ListBox` rather than `Control` or `UserControl`.